# Check 2 Extents with Disjoint in Arcpy - Wrong Result

Tags: arcpy, intersection, extents

I'm now facing a problem using Disjoint in Arcpy to check if 2 extents are intersected.

I have 2 extents like this:

- Ext1: 33206887.500051 5890587.49999999 33460887.500051 6060887.49999999 NaN NaN NaN NaN
- Ext2: 33346031.7877 5892265.95 33395320.8209 5927481.3861 NaN NaN NaN NaN

According to my shape and raster, the shape with Ext2 is completely inside the raster with Ext1.

But unfortunately, using

```
Ext1.disjoint(Ext2)
```

leads to the "True"-result, which indicates that the 2 extents share no common intersection.

It drives me really crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extents need to be in the same projection for `disjoint` to work.

Here I have an mxd with two data frames. Each data frame has the same extent but two different projections. In this case `disjoint` returns `True`:

```
>>> mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument ("CURRENT")
>>> dfs = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames (mxd)
>>> df1 = dfs [0]
>>> df2 = dfs [1]
>>> ex1 = df1.extent
>>> ex2 = df2.extent
>>> ex1.disjoint (ex2)
True
```

I project my second extent into the same projection as my first and `disjoint` returns `False`:

```
>>> sr = ex1.spatialReference
>>> ex2proj = ex2.projectAs (sr)
>>> ex1.disjoint (ex2proj)
False
>>>
```

[image]

Comment: It seems to be really the problem! Thank you so much!